# What's the different between supportsAVCaptureSessionPreset and canSetSessionPreset

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

In `AVCaptureDevice`, I can use `supportsAVCaptureSessionPreset`.

In `AVCaptureSession`, I Can use `canSetSessionPreset`.

What's the different between them, for they both detect whether a session preset is avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the device and the session not being in sync. The session may support 4K thinking it is still connected to the old device  but once you connect the input it crashes saying the preset is not supported because the new device is only 720P.  On the other hand going up from 720P to 4k, Setting it to 4K is not allowed without the new input added to the session. It  will cause your preset to remain in 720P. I currently use both but I wonder if I can simply use the device without using the session.

This happens when switching between the back and front iPhone cameras.